# Jquery code works on one page and doesn't works on another page

Tags: jquery

I have one file with jquery code, I connect it to two different pages, because one part of code for the one page, second for another. But code for the second page doesn't works and jquery throws error in code for the first page. But there are no errors on the first page with same code. **Error on the second page:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slick is not a function
    at runSlick (script.js:15)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:19)
    at mightThrow (jquery-3.2.1.js:3583)
    at process (jquery-3.2.1.js:3651)
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    //CODE FOR THE FIRST PAGE
    //Main Slider
    var maxWidth = 992,
        slickVar = {
            dots: true,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: maxWidth,
                    settings: 'unslick'
                }
            ]
        },
        runSlick = function() {
            $('.sl').slick(slickVar);
        };

// slick initialization while document ready
    runSlick();

// listen to jQuery's window resize
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        var width = $(window).width();
        if(width < maxWidth) {
            // reinit slick while window's width is less than maximum width (992px)
            runSlick();
        }
    }).resize();

    //hide slider elements if window's width is less than maximum width (992px)
    $(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(this).width() < maxWidth) {
        $('.hidden').addClass('d-none');
    } else {
        $('.hidden').removeClass('d-none');
    }
}).resize();

    //Slider in clients section
    $('.sl-2').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1500,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 1500
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplaySpeed: 1500
                }
            }
        ]

    });

    //show image on hover over features-list element
    $('.features-list li>.feature-top').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).find('.top-wrapper').addClass('d-none');
            $(this).css({
                'padding': '0',
                'background-color': '#f5f5f5'
            });
            $(this).find('.hover-content').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        function() {
            $(this).find('.top-wrapper').removeClass('d-none');
            $(this).css({
                'padding': '20px 0',
                'background-color': '#ffea00'
            });
            $(this).find('.hover-content').fadeOut(50);
        }
    );

    //Isotope in works section
     $('.grid').isotope({
        // main isotope options
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 15,
            isFitWidth: true
        }
    });
//END OF CODE FOR THE FIRST PAGE

//CODE FOR THE SECOND PAGE
        $(".portfolio-menu-link").click(function () {
            $(".portfolio-menu-link").removeClass("active-portfolio-link");
            $(this).addClass("active-portfolio-link");
        });
});
```

Comment: You haven't included whatever library enables the `slick()` method in the page which doesn't work. Either that or you've placed the library *before* you reference jQuery itself.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have slick() only on the first page and don't have it on another. Is it means that I need to have another jquery file for second page?

Comment: Yes. Any page you include your jQuery code on will need it, as you reference it. The fact that it's not used on the page is irrelevant. The jQuery references it, so it needs to be loaded.

Comment: Just to mention that `.slick()` is [Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I know, I have it on the first page, but don't have on another.

Comment: So don't call it on the other then. The error is thrown because you call it... And it's undefined on that one.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your help! You can add your answer to Answers section and I mark it as correct.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Is there any way that I can make this slick call only on the first page and not call on second? Or it's better to create another jquery file for second page without slick?

Comment: @Belial glad it fixed your issue. I added the answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have slick() only on the first page and don't have it on another. Is it means that I need to have another jquery file for second page?

Yes. Any page you include your jQuery code on will need it, as you reference it. The fact that it's not used on the page is irrelevant. The jQuery references it, so it needs to be loaded.

If you want to check if the element you're calling the Slick Slider on exists in the DOM first (to avoid having to separate your jQuery in to multiple files for each page) you could do this:

```
var $sl2 = $('.sl-2');
if ($sl2.length) {
  $sl2.slick({ 
    infinite: true,
    // settings...
  });
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help